# How to place two tikz matrices next to one another with double lined arrow between them

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi I have two tikz matrices that I created. I want to place the matrix named b on the right side of the matrix named a. The two matrices must fit side by side parallel to each other on the page. I'm not sure how to do this. I also would like to draw a quite large double lined arrow in tikz that points from matrix a to matrix b. If I try to connect the two matrices with the code:

`\draw [arrow style]  (a) --  (b);` it gives me a weird line drawn from matrix b downwards.

Here is the code I already tried.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Let's input our packages and styles;


% \input{packages.tex}

% \input{styles.tex}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{ifthen}


\title{generic flow chart}

\author{Daniel}

\date{December 2022}

\begin{document}



%%% The tikz packages im using;




\usetikzlibrary{ arrows.meta, 
   calc, chains,
 positioning, 
 shadows, shapes}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     The styles im using; %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tikzstyle{arrow style} = [-{Latex[scale = 1.5]} , semithick]
 
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% This is the start of my tikz figure  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [draw , column sep=0.1cm , row sep = 1cm](a) at (0,0)
{
;&   \draw node(a)[align = left]   {\textbf{\small REAL WORLD}};\\
     \draw node(b)[align = left]   {\textbf{\large Unknown} \\ \textbf{\large probability} }; &; 
 &   \draw  node(c)[align = left] {\textbf{\large Observed} \\ \textbf{\large Data}};\\
     \draw node(d)[align = left]      {\textbf{P}}; &; &\draw  node(e)[align = left] {$\mathbf{x} = (x_{1} , x_{2} , \dots x_{n})$};\\
;& ; & \draw  node(f)[align = left]{$\hat{\theta} = s(\mathbf{x})$};\\
;&  \draw node(a)[align = left]   {\textbf{\small STATISTIC OF INTEREST}};\\
};

% Arrows on first matrix:


\draw [arrow style]  (d) --  (e);

\draw [arrow style]  (e) --  (f);

\matrix [draw , column sep=0.1cm , row sep = 1cm](b) at (0,-12)
{
;&   \draw node(a)[align = left]   {\textbf{\small BOOTSTRAP WORLD}};\\
     \draw node(b)[align = left]   {\textbf{\large Estimated} \\ \textbf{\large Probability} \\ \textbf{\large Model}}; &; 
 &   \draw  node(c)[align = left] {\textbf{\large Bootstrap} \\ \textbf{\large Sample}};\\
     \draw node(d)[align = left]      {$\mathbf{\hat{P}}$}; &; &\draw  node(e)[align = left] {$\mathbf{x}^{*} = (x_{1}^{*} , x_{2}^{*} , \dots x_{n}^{*})$};\\
;& ; & \draw  node(f)[align = left]{${\hat{\theta}}^{*} = s(\mathbf{x}^{*})$};\\
;&  \draw node(a)[align = left]   {\textbf{\small STATISTIC OF INTEREST}};\\
};

 % arrows on second matrix;


\draw [arrow style]  (d) --  (e);

\draw [arrow style]  (e) --  (f);

\draw [arrow style]  (a) --  (b);

% connecting the big matrices with a double arrow;







\end{tikzpicture}   


\end{document}
```

And here is the picture i'm roughly trying to replicate in tikz:

[image]

My current output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code fragment compilable, i.e. extend it to complete small document.

Comment: Note updated version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Well, as you can see, I redesign your image (a lot). Maybe you will liked . So the following MWE (written more or less from scratch) should serve (at least) as starting point in the case if you will redesign above image according to your taste:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\cellalign{bc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                shadows}

 %%% Start of my tikz figure %%%%%
\begin{document}
\tikzset{  > = Straight Barb,
    F/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=white, drop shadow,
                fit=#1},
    M/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                nodes = {font=\linespread{0.84}\small\bfseries, align=center},
                column sep=2em, row sep=1ex},
every label/.append style = {font=\bfseries, inner sep=0pt},
        }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =3em]
\matrix (m1)    [M, label={[name=A] REAL WORLD}, 
                    label={[name=B] below:statistic of interest}]
{
\makecell{Unknown \\ probability\\ model} 
    &   \makecell{Observed \\ Data}             \\
$P$ &   $\mathbf{\dot{x}} = (x_1,x_1,\dotsc,x_b)$  \\[5ex]
    &   $\hat{\theta} = s(\mathbf{x})$          \\
};
\draw[->]   (m1-2-1) -- (m1-2-2);
\draw[->]   (m1-2-2) -- (m1-3-2);
%%%%%%%%%%%% second matrix
\matrix (m2)    [M, label={[name=C] BOOTSTRAP WORLD},
                    label={[name=D] below:bootstrap replication},
                 right=of m1]
{
\makecell{Unknown \\ probability\\ model}
            &   \makecell{Observed \\ Data}             \\
$\hat{P}$   &   $\mathbf{\dot{x}} = (x_1^*,x_1^*,\dotsc,x_b^*)$  \\[5ex]
            &   $\hat{\theta}^* = s(\mathbf{x}^*)$          \\
};
\draw[->]   (m2-2-1) -- (m2-2-2);
\draw[->]   (m2-2-2) -- (m2-3-2);
%
\draw[double, double distance=1pt,->]   (m1-2-2) -- (m2-2-1);

\scoped[on background layer]
{\node[F=(A) (m1) (B)] {};
 \node[F=(C) (m2) (D)] {};
}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```